# Do we need to change the email deliverablity to 'all emails' if we are using Send Email action in one of the flows?

Tags: community, visual-workflow, send-email, deliverability

I have a flow which sends and email to queue members whenever a case is created from the community, however it was not going through until I changed the email deliverability to 'All emails'. Will that be a problem or not a best practice, if yes what is the other solution.

Comment: Yes, you need to set `All Email` in order for automation email to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to test the functionality in sandbox without sending test emails to real time users we will keep the email deliverability to '`No access`' or '`System email only`'. If you set the email deliverability to `All email` unnecessarily users will get the test email notifications. These mails are triggered from workflow/process builder/flow/triggers/apex classes.

If you want to test the email notifications which are triggered by `workflow/process builder/flow/triggers/apex classes` at that time you can enable the the email deliverability to `All email` and turn off once the testing is completed in sandbox.

> No access—Allows only password reset emails. Prevents all other
> outbound email to and from users.
>
> System email only—Allows only
> automatically generated emails, such as new user and password reset
> emails.
>
> All email—Allows all types of outbound email. Default for new
> orgs that aren’t sandboxes.

Refer the [Guidelines for Configuring Deliverability Settings for Emails Sent from Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emailadmin_deliverability.htm&type=5)